# Is there any way in Twitter for your replies to other users not appearing in your timeline?

Tags: twitter

Time ago, when you replied to another user it didnt appear in your timeline, not at least in the "tweets" section of your timeline (it appeared in tweets and replies if I recall correctly) . But now when you reply it appears in the timeline with the original tweet you are responding to embeded in your tweet. Is there any way to avoid this and to return to the interface Twitter used to have about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replies are still in *Tweets and Replies* section but for other users who ever visit your profile. For you all your tweets and replies will show on your Timeline. This is latest interface of Twitter and I don't see any way to use any other interface other than current one.

Comment: Oh, so your profile actually looks different for you than it does for other users? How weird...